# Why is not there jar version of axis2 1.7.3 in Maven repository?

Tags: eclipse, maven, apache-axis

I'm trying to download the axis2 1.7.3 through Eclipse maven. I coudn't download the jar file. In the maven central repocitery, they don't have the jar.
[Maven Repository Link](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.axis2%22%20AND%20a%3A%22axis2%22)

Why isn't there jar version and how to configur maven to have it on my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The artifact [`org.apache.axis2:axis2`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/axis2/axis2/) was an uber-jar that consisted of every module of Axis2 packaged in a single fat JAR. This special artifact [was removed](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/release-notes/1.6.4.html) in version 1.6.4 of Axis2:

> Please note that in order to simplify the build and release process, the document distribution and all-in-one JARs have been removed in this release.

As such, you can't have a dependency on this JAR anymore, and you need to add dependencies to each wanted module separately. An example is [`axis2-jaxws`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/axis2/axis2-jaxws/) (related [web site](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/jaxws-guide.html)).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the POM file for that artifact, it is not a JAR.  It is packaged as a POM file.

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/axis2/axis2/1.7.3/axis2-1.7.3.pom

As it is packaged as a pom, there is no jar artifact at those maven coordinates.  So there will be no JAR file to download.  If you look at the list you referenced, there is no JAR file in central.

[image]

It seems like the classes you are looking for are in another JAR artifact deployed as part of axis2

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.axis2%22

Comment: Do you know why they removed the jar while the old version such as 1.6.2 has jar version?

Comment: The other answer provides that information.  It's a case where the new release changed how it packaged up its classes.  Looks to be an intentional repackaging.